# "Sorry something went wrong with adding the app. Click to retry"

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-addin

I am unable to remove the app, it is corrupted. Can any give example using PowerShell how to uninstall the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove app using following powershell command

```
$instances = Get-SPAppInstance -Web <URL>

$instance = $instances | where {$_.Title -eq '<app_title>'}

Uninstall-SPAppInstance -Identity $instance
```

replace `<URL>` with site collection url
and `<app_title>` with title of the app you want to remove

Comment: I already tried like this i am getting error for -Web,unable to identify the key word

Comment: Which error? Which app? Have you checked the logs? You really need to specify more information.

Answer (score 0):

If the PowerShell doesn't work check the following link

http://sujeewa.com/2015/06/remove-corrupted-app-from-the-farm/